# How do I install a Minecraft texture pack on a Windows 10 computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I'm trying to install a texture pack for Minecraft on my Windows 10 PC. I'm trying to open `%appdata%` to get to the Minecraft folder, but it is just opening the Bing website, it wont take me to the folder.

How can I get to the Texture Pack folder for Minecraft on Windows 10?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Where are you typing `%appdata%`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Run' command box to open AppData. This can be accessed by either:

1. Holding the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and press <kbd>R</kbd> to open 'Run', or
2. Right-Clicking on the Start Menu button and click 'Run':
   [image: Run command in context menu]

Once you've opened the Run box, type `%appdata%` and Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the AppData folder. From there it's just a matter of going to `.minecraft\resourcepacks` to install your texture pack.

#### References:

- [iSunshare - 5 Ways to Open Run in Windows 10](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-open-run-in-windows-10.html)